# Wieso schmeißt man jemanden heraus, nicht hinaus?

Tags: english-to-german, usage, vocabulary

Wenn ein Türsteher -- oder Rausschmeißer, meines Wörterbuchs nach -- will, dass jemand einen Klub unbedingt und sofort verlässt, "schmeißt er ihn heraus".  Aber wieso "heraus"?  Wie ich es verstehe, "her" bedeutet *zu mir*, während "hin" *weg von mir* bedeutet.  Wäre es nicht besser zu sagen, "Der Türsteher schmeißt ihn **hinaus**"?

Wenn ich zu DeepL.com gehe und "The bouncer kicked him out" eingebe, bekomme ich als Übersetzung:

> Der Türsteher hat ihn rausgeschmissen.

> Der Türsteher hat ihn rausgeworfen

Also, immer mit "(he)raus".

Es kann total sein, dass ich etwas nicht richtig verstehe.  Aber wenn jemand eine Erklärung hat, wäre ich dankbar.

Comment: "Hin-" und "her-" sind nur aus Sprechersicht relevant. Die ist aber in dem Zusammenhang gar nicht spannend, da sowohl der Werfer aus auch der Geworfene i.A. woanders sind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Vorsilbe "raus-" im Verb "rausschmeißen" kann sowohl eine Kurzform von "heraus" sein als auch eine Kurzform von "hinaus". Siehe zum Beispiel [im Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/raus)

> [1] schnell gesprochenes, in flüssiger Rede und umgangssprachlich und in vielen Dialekten auftauchendes heraus oder hinaus

Der "Rausschmeißer" schmeißt also tatsächlich jemanden hinaus (von innen betrachtet). Die Form "hinausschmeißen" ist eher selten und wird meiner Erfahrung eher für Dinge verwendet als für Personen.

Was es tatsächlich gibt, ist ein Synonym für die Aufgabe eines "Rausschmeißers" auf einer etwas höheren sprachlichen Ebene: Er kann jemanden "hinauswerfen".

Comment: Ich habe kurz im DWDS-Korpus geschaut: *herauswerfen* ist seltener als *hinauswerfen*; die jeweils ersten Treffer sind *sämtliche Gläser herausgeworfen* und *sich als Bürgerlicher aus einer adligen Gesellschaft hinauswerfen lassen*.

Answer (score 1):

Die Unterscheidung zwischen Adverben, die mit her- vs. hin- beginnen, ist eher die Domäne grammatischer Pedanten und Präskriptivisten als die der tatsächlichen Sprachnutzung.

Die meisten Sprecher verwenden diese als Synonyme; viele wissen wohl gar nicht, was theoretisch der Unterschied dazwischen sein sollte. Deshalb hat es auch wenig Sinn, darüber zu philosophieren, warum sie in bestimmten Phrasen nicht "korrekt" verwendet werden.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn wir für den Moment akzeptieren, daß *hin* eine Bewegung weg vom Sprecher und *her* eine auf den Sprecher zu bezeichnet, dann muß daraus nicht folgen, daß *hinaus* und *heraus* sich entsprechend verhalten. Es handelt sich schließlich um eigenständige Wörter.

Wahrscheinlich gibt es auch wenig Grund, in Situationen wie den folgenden verschiedene Verben zu benutzen; der Kontext macht die Sache ohnehin klar.

> Als wir an der Bar vorbeikamen, sahen wir, wie ein Gast herausgeworfen wurde.
>
> Wir waren sehr erleichtert, als die Tischnachbarn endlich hinausgeworfen wurden.

Bei Sätzen wie *man hat uns …geworfen* weiß man auch nicht, ob man *hinaus* wählen soll, weil man ja mal drin war, oder *heraus*, weil man jetzt draußen ist. Entsprechend findet man beide Varianten.

Wenn es mal einen solchen Unterschied zwischen *hinaus* und *heraus* gegeben haben sollte, ist er lang verwischt.

Answer (score -1):

Da kommt wohl einiges zusammen. Der übliche in der Frage vorgegebene Ansatz einer verkürzten Form von *her-aus* bzw. *hin-aus* ist zwar begründet aber kurzsichtig und demnach abzulehnen.

Im Prinzip ist der Ansatz unproblematisch. Da umgangangssprachlich auch *hier* + *raus* verwendet wird insbesonder als Interjektion “Raus hier!", kann man analog mit englisch *outta here* schließen, dass eine Form von Beugung zu grunde liegt, die in andern Beispielen ganz anders sein kann  aber nicht grammatisch markiert wird, jedenfalls nicht mehr. Dagegen ist es unnütz davon auszugehen, *hin und her* wäre der einzig mögliche Kontrast.

Daher erübrigen sich weitere Überlegungen eigentlich. Das ist aber auch genau der Grund, aus dem nicht darüber nachgedacht wird und weitere Anschlussmöglichkeiten im urindoeuropäischen Lexikon übersehen werden, zumal sich die Germanistik an mittelalterlicher Überlieferung festhält; wie gesagt nicht unbegründet.

Als Gegenbeispiele bieten sich an: lateinisch *re-*, Herkunft ungewiss; urie. **srew*, vgl. *ins Wasser fallen*, *den Boden mit jemandem schrubben*; urie. **ker-*, quasi Herr Ausschmeißer, bzw. Heerzog; **ḱers-*, vgl. *rausch*, *rausgeschmissenes Geld* (wie in Saus und Braus), ebenso **Hreth₂-*, vgl. *rasch* (doch da wo man *rasch* sagt, sagt man *naus*); **wréh₂ds*, vgl. engl. *rash* (so Wiktionary Ety. 6: “... variant of *esrachier* (“to eradicate, get rid of”), from Latin *exrādīcāre, ērādīcāre* ..."); un dso weiter, aber niche tsofort.